# calendar API How to search for Default / None / Empty privateExtendedProperty in Calendar Events list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

How can i search for default / none / empty privateExtendedProperty in Calendar events list optionalArgs?

```
// Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs)
var data = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
//  privateExtendedProperty: default //Syntax error. (line ..., file "...")
//  privateExtendedProperty:         //Syntax error. (line ..., file "...")
//  privateExtendedProperty: "mytag=tag" // returns the 1 event with that tag.
//  privateExtendedProperty: "mytag<>tag" //ScriptError: A key or value missing in the extended_properties_match.
//  privateExtendedProperty: "mytag!=tag" //no results
//  privateExtendedProperty: "*!=*" // no results
//  privateExtendedProperty: "!=" // no rusults
//  privateExtendedProperty: "null=null" // no rusults
//  privateExtendedProperty: null //All results (including the ones with privateExtendedProperty)
//  privateExtendedProperty: undefined //All results
//  privateExtendedProperty: "" //ScriptError: A key or value missing in the extended_properties_match.
});
```

If i use "privateExtendedProperty: "mytag=tag"" i find the events with that tag, but i want to find all event that have no tag.

Or i would like to filter all events edited outside of my app.

Ps. I use google calendar API 3.0 in combination with Google apps Script.

Comment: did you mean == and not = ? if yes, use !=

Comment: Hi noogui, Thank you. No the api manual say use: = not ==. I tried != but that gives me no result at all.

Comment: Hi @FrankSenders
Did you find the answer?..

Comment: @Rodion no i didn't find the answer to this question. But i did download all calendar events and after that i used a loop to select the ones i needed.

Comment: thanks for this question, maybe someone could post it in a google forum?